# Parse a json string to get specific field values

Tags: json, string

I am getting below Jsonstring. Now I need to get value for Salesforce_ABT__c in a string Salesforce. Can someone please help me?

**JSON String:**

```
   loginUserJson@{"attributes":{"type":"User","url":"/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/User/005F0000002ex2jIAA"},"Id":"005F0000002ex2jIAA","Name":"iRep Admin3","IsActive":true,"Email":"anilkumar.lingaraju@abbvie.com","SmallPhotoUrl":"https://abv-irep-us--NGT--c.cs71.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T","Primary_Territory_vod__c":"JBB00","User_Franchise_abv__c":"GI Care","Salesforce_ABT__c":"HOMEOFFICE","ProfileId":"00eA0000000wwNpIAI","Profile":{"attributes":{"type":"Profile","url":"/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Profile/00eA0000000wwNpIAI"},"Name":"System Administrator","Id":"00eA0000000wwNpIAI"}}
```

I am trying to do below approach but it gives error.

**Error**

```
 loginuser = [Select Id,Name,IsActive,email,SmallPhotoUrl, Primary_Territory_vod__c, User_Franchise_abv__c,Salesforce_ABT__c, Profile.Name from User where Id = :UserInfo.GetUserId()];    
        loginUserJson = JSON.serialize(loginuser);
       JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(loginUserJson);
        system.debug('loginUserJson@'+loginUserJson);
        String Franchise= json.getString('User_Franchise_abv__c');
        String Salesforce= jsonObject.getString('Salesforce_ABT__c');
        String Territory= jsonObject.getString('Primary_Territory_vod__c');
```

But is gives error JSONObject is invalid type. Please help me doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always worth pasting JSON into e.g. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to more easily see it's structure.

The Apex [JSON class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) is usually the best thing to use. You can do this if its a small bit of code:

```
Map<String, Object> p = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(loginUserJson);
String Franchise = (String) p.get('User_Franchise_abv__c');
...
```

Or if you are doing a lot of manipulation of the JSON you can generate classes to represent the data using [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) and work with those.

(I presume the code you post is a contrived example; in it you could access the data using `loginuser` directly without going via JSON.)

Comment: I like jsbeautifier which works great for JSON too. But yeah good advice.